# Haskell package version

Tags: haskell, cabal

Is there a simple way of getting the version of the current package?  I want to add a line like this at the beginning of `main`

```
putStrLn $ "MyFabApp, version " ++ show(version)
```

where `version :: Data.Version`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can my-program.hs get its version number from my-program.cabal at build time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892586/how-can-my-program-hs-get-its-version-number-from-my-program-cabal-at-build-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure can. See this earlier answer:

- [How can my Haskell program or library find its version number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892586/how-can-my-program-hs-get-its-version-number-from-my-program-cabal-at-build-time)

Comment: perfect, thanks - searching for 'haskell version' missed that one :\