# How do I check what version of a package is installed with stack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Within my project's .cabal file I've got the following under the `executable` section:

```
executable ArchPkgstatsScraper
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  main-is:             Main.hs
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:       base
                       , ArchPkgStatsScraper
                       , text
                       , conduit
                       , html-conduit
                       , http-conduit
                       , xml-conduit
                       , resourcet
                       , transformers
```

After I've successfully installed / built the above with stack, how could I check which version of xml-conduit is installed?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The command

```
stack ls dependencies
```

or for older version of stack:

```
stack list-dependencies
```

will list every dependency installed for the current project, along with its version.

Comment: Might also be useful for someone: `stack dot --external`. Thanks https://twitter.com/snoyberg/status/793870778672541696

Comment: Useful answer (upvoted), but by default it only lists the dependencies of the 'production' code. If you wish to see dependencies of your test code, you can use `stack list-dependencies --test`.

Comment: For future visitors, `stack list-dependencies` is being deprecated in favour of `stack ls dependencies`.

Answer (score 12):

The  new  command  is going to be

```
stack ls dependencies
```

which is replacement of `stack list-dependencies`

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/seek-oss/serverless-haskell/issues/38)